# SVG showing wrong on Safari 12

Tags: angular, svg, sass

I have a countdown SVG working on Angular+2, it goes red 10 seconds before ends. On Chrome and Firefox style works well but on Safari it shows wrong as you can see on images. I need it to show the same style on Chrome and Safari. I have been trying everything with overflow but it doesn't work.

SVG image on Chrome:

[image: Chrome SVG]

SVG image on Safari:

[image: Safari SVG]

Angular html code:

```
<!-- Countdown timer animation Mobile -->
<div [className]="myClass">
  <svg style="fill: rgba (0,0,0,0.0001);" width="136" height="136" *showItSizes="{max: 767}">
    <circle r="64" cy="64" cx="63"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<!-- Countdown timer animation Desktop-->
<div [className]="myClass">
  <svg style="fill: rgba (0,0,0,0.0001);" width="146" height="145" *showItSizes="{min: 768}">
    <circle r="69.85699" cy="66" cx="68"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<!-- countdown container -->
<div class="logout-card__countdown">
  <p class="logout-card__countdown--start">{{start}}</p>
  <span class="logout-card__countdown--text">segundos</span>
</div>
```

SCSS for SVG:

```
svg {
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(-90deg);
    fill: rgba (0,0,0,0.0001);

    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: visible;

    circle {
      stroke-dasharray: 410px;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke-width: 11px;
      fill-opacity: 0.01;
      animation: countdown 60s linear forwards;
    }

    @keyframes countdown {
      from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
      }
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 410px;
      }
    }
  }

  &__countdown{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 114px;

    &--start{
      font-size: 50.5px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }

    &--text{
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely surprised you are having problems.  You are mixing 3D transforms, overflow and border radiuses.

I suggest you fix your SVG:

- Make the SVG the correct size instead of relying on overflow.
- Get rid of the border radius. I'm not even sure why you have it.
- Use a simple rotate transform inside the SVG, and adjust your animation to get the countdown going in the correct direction.

I can't test with Safari, but I'm hoping this simplified version works better for you. It should do:

```css
svg {
  fill: rgba (0,0,0,0.0001);
}

svg circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 440px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 11px;
  fill-opacity: 0.01;
  animation: countdown 60s linear forwards;
  stroke: orange;
}

@keyframes countdown {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -440px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Countdown timer animation Desktop-->
<div className="myClass">
  <svg width="152" height="152">
    <circle r="70" cx="76" cy="76" transform="rotate(-90,76,76)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Update**

I forgot that Safari has a bug where it doesn't correctly handle negative `stroke-dashoffset` values.  Here's a new version with a workaround.

```css
svg {
  fill: rgba (0,0,0,0.0001);
}

svg circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 440px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 880px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 11px;
  fill-opacity: 0.01;
  animation: countdown 60s linear forwards;
  stroke: orange;
}

@keyframes countdown {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 440px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Countdown timer animation Desktop-->
<div className="myClass">
  <svg width="152" height="152">
    <circle r="70" cx="76" cy="76" transform="rotate(-90,76,76)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: tried it for you in latest chrome and safari. In Chrome it works fine. In Safari you get an inverted behavior, it paints out a ring instead of removing/disappearing animation, with the same starting pints. But the thickness  of the stroke is the same

Comment: Thanks for testing. I forgot that Safari has a bug with negative dashoffsets.  I have added a new version that hopefully should work on Safari now.

Comment: Thanks Paul!! I was using border-radious so I could do a slim line on the center of the orange stroke. Problema was fixed for iOS but design is wrong. Is there any way to change the zindex of the slim line to go to the back?
Here is my pen https://codepen.io/julioorellana/pen/PxOpvo

Comment: Just put the thin circle before the other circle. In SVG things are drawn from back to front. https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/bQaMPG